# Where can I find the dividend history for a stock?

Tags: dividends, online-data-source, historical-data

Where can I find the dividend history for a stock? Do you recommend any site where this information is easily accessible?

Answer (score 4):

[Google Finance](http://finance.google.com) gives you this information.

Comment: How accurate is Google Finance?

Comment: Haven't cross-checked but it seems pretty accurate.  Don't think they put the dividend flags on the graph without good reason.

Comment: So after I click on a stock name (GOOG), I can see the stock prices. How do you see the dividends?

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the required company's website and check out their investor section. Here is an example from [GE](http://www.ge.com/investors/stock_info/dividend_history.html) and [Apple](http://www.apple.com/investor/).

Answer (score 1):

I second @DumbCoder, every company seems to have its own way of displaying the next dividend date and the actual dividend.

I keep track of this information and try my best to make it available for free through my little iphone web app here

http://divies.nazabe.com